# See if $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(\ln n)^{-20}$ converge

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I want some help here, use comparison test to see if it converges or diverge. $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(\ln n)^{-20}$. This is $\sum \frac{1}{(\ln n)^{20}}$. So it's $\geq 0$, I wonder if it's using $\sum \frac{1}{n^{20}}$ to compare it to, because then $\sum \frac{1}{n^{20}}$ converge and if you compare it then $\sum \frac{1}{(\ln n)^{20}}$ does too

Comment: Compare with $\sum\frac{1}{n}$ - which, as we know, diverges. Note that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(\ln n)^{20}}{n}=0$.

Comment: This is a comment on your idea: Which is bigger eventually: $n$, or $\ln n$? So, which is bigger eventually: $1/n$ or $1/\ln n$? Should $1/\ln n$ be bigger (!), you won't be able to conclude that the convergence of the smaller $1/n^{20}$ implies the convergence of the larger $1/(\ln n )^{20}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see if we can use the comparison test with $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(\ln n)^{-20}$ and $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n^{-20}$.

We know that $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n^{-20}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{20}}$$ converges,
so to show that another series converges by comparison we need to show that the value is **less than** this value.

Note that:
$$n\geq \ln n$$
So then:
$$\frac{1}{n}\leq\frac{1}{\ln n}\implies \frac{1}{n^{20}}\leq\frac{1}{(\ln n)^{20}}$$

Which implies that our sum is **bigger** than the convergent value. Could be $\infty$, or an actual number, but this application doesn't show it.

As @Stinking Bishop mentioned, if you compare with $\sum\frac{1}{n}$ via $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(\ln n)^{20}}{n}=0$ you see that:

$$\infty<\sum\frac{1}{n}\leq\sum(\ln n)^{-20}$$
Thus, the sum diverges.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to point out is: $\ln n < n^{\alpha}$ for any $\alpha > 0$ and for sufficiently large $n$. This means $(\ln n)^{20} < n^{20\alpha}\implies \displaystyle \sum \dfrac{1}{(\ln n)^{20}} \ge \displaystyle \sum \dfrac{1}{n^{20\alpha}}=\infty$ if $ 20\alpha \le 1$. Thus to see the series diverges to $\infty$, you can take $\alpha  = \dfrac{1}{25}$.